# P4VS Visual Studio 2010 Not Updating Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perforce

In option, data retrieval is set to 10 min but P4VS never updates any file automatically.  Only way to update a file is to first know which file has been changed by someone else and then do forced "Get Revision". One would assume that P4VS will update files at least when VS is launched.

Upon further investigation, when the workspace is viewed in P4V, those files are also not updated even though the depot contains updated files.  P4sync in P4V workspace does not refresh any files.  In fact the workspace in P4V contains files in the same state as existed on the day the workspace was created.

What is missing?

Comment: If a "p4 sync" fails to update the files in either P4VS or P4V it suggests some underlying problem that's not specific to either.  What happens if you run "p4 sync" from the command line?  The output might help point the way to a solution.

Comment: I tried running p4 sync but it prompted "create a client first ..." not knowing what client it was asking me to create, I exited.

Comment: To run 'p4 sync' from the command line, you have to specify three things: (1) the P4PORT address of the server to connect to, (2) your P4USER username, and (3) The P4CLIENT workspace name that you are using on this machine. On your commandline, run 'p4 set' to see if any of those variables are already set, then run 'set P4PORT=...', 'set P4USER=...', and 'set P4CLIENT=...' to specify the ones that aren't already set. Then you can run a command like 'p4 sync' to see what it reports about the current state of your workspace.

Comment: For a basic overview of what a client (workspace) is, see this: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v-gs/01_p4v-gs.html

Comment: @BryanPendleton when I run p4 sync with all those parameters, it throws "Client '<machine name>' unknown - use 'client' command to create it."  I am new to P4 but I find it strange that P4VS is able to get files without this so called "client" and also, why didn't they put this option to sync all in P4VS. In their documentation they boast that P4VS is a "full fledged" client. By the way, in workspace, nothing happens even when I check get all updates automatically. P4 is such a bad choice. Looking for something else now after wasting 4 days.

Comment: P4V is even more funnier.  Nothing happens no matter how you try to update from depot. Files remains the same unless you go click on each one of them individually and sync to head.

Comment: If you're using Perforce you have a client, I promise.  In either P4V or P4VS you see your client (also called a "workspace" or "client workspace") if you look at the connection info.  In P4V your workspace name is displayed right above your files; in P4VS you use View > Toolbars > P4 Connection.

I *highly* recommend giving Perforce technical support a call rather than wasting any more time -- this is probably something that'll be easily resolved with a fifteen minute support call.  Or post on forums.perforce.com since this needs a conversation and stackoverflow discourages back-and-forth.